# Exclude jar flom classpath in Ant

Tags: java, ant, build, path, classpath

How can I exclude jars included in one classpath variable from another classpath variable in Ant? I have a `myclasspath1` property that contains all jars I want to include and `myclasspath2` with a list of other jar. I want to get classpath3 that includes all jars from classpath1 that are not in classpath2. Here is what I came up with for one jar:

```
<path id="my.classpath1">
   <pathelement path="${myClasspath1}"/>
</path>

<!-- at the end I want to get all jars concatenated into a string -->
<pathconvert pathsep="," property="my.classpath3" refid="my.classpath1">
   <mapper type="flatten"/>
   <map from="excluded.jar" to="" />
</pathconvert>
```

How can exclude all jars included in `myclasspath2` instead?

Comment: Have you seen [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205592/exclude-jar-from-ant-classpath) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise that your classpath management should be explicit as you can make them, for example:

```
<path id="my.classpath1">
  <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
    <includes name="*.jar"/>
    <excludes name="foo.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</path>

<path id="my.classpath2">
  <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
    <includes name="*.jar"/>
    <excludes name="bar.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</path>

<path id="my.classpath3">
  <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
    <includes name="foo.jar"/>
    <includes name="bar.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</path>
```

Classpath management is a pain.... The best solution would be to use a dependency manager like [apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) . There are also ANT tasks available for Maven. Both would download jars automatically from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) and are capable of managing your classpaths for you.